# Error in uploading file (from public url) to onedrive using REST API

Tags: javascript, api, rest, onedrive

I am getting an when trying to upload a file to Microsoft OneDrive using its REST API. The file is located on another site(MSDN for this example). Is there a way to upload a file(using its full url path) to onedrive without downloading it first?

> REST query -
>   https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/skydrive/files/fileurl?access_token=mytoken

**Error**

> {    "error": {
>         "code": "request_url_invalid", 
>         "message": "The URL contains the path 'blogs.msdn.com', which isn't supported."    } }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your client will need to download the URL and then POST/PUT the content to a specific file name. You cannot specify a URL to another resource instead of the name.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Just to confirm- even if the link is a direct file link (clicking it would download the file), the file needs to be downloaded on client machine before POSTing ?

Comment: Unfortunately yes. Hopefully this will change in the future.